# Java Code - Comparing last 4 letters

Tags: java

Implement a method that returns true if the final four character substrings of `s1` and `s2` are equal. If the length of either string is less than 4, the method should return false.

You may use the method `s.substring(n, m)` that yields the substring of `s` beginning at index `n` and ending at index `m-1`.

As an answer I delivered following code, I was just wondering whether I did it in a correct way:

```
public static boolean compareLast4 (String s1, String s2) {
    s1len = s1.length;
    s2len = s2.length;
    if (s1lan < 4 || s2len < 4)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1len; i++)
        if (s1.substring() - 4.equals(s2.length() - 4))
            return true;
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile it? Getting an error in compilation is a pretty good hint you did not do it in a correct way :)

Comment: I do not think this compiles :), is "if(s1.substring()-4.equals(s2.length()-4))" correct?

Comment: Meh, I don't see why the -1s are necessary. This looks like there was a genuine attempt, even though it is a 'help with my homework' question.

Comment: @ icedwater, it was a question I had during my exam, and this is the answer I wrote on the answer booklet, I am not too sure, whether it is the correct way of doing it or not, if yes I would like to estimate how many points I could get out of 10, since ten was the full mark for the question.

Comment: I hate to sound negative, but there are very many things wrong with the code that you've shown.  How many marks you get out of 10 really depends on the generosity of the marker.  Why don't you try running this in an IDE, see what compile errors you get, then have a go at fixing them?  Then, try to write a test for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
public static boolean compareLast4 (String s1, String s2) 
{
    if (s1.length() < 4 || s2.length() < 4)
        return false;
    return s1.substring(s1.length() - 4).equals(s2.substring(s2.length()-4));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the specific answer (I simply hate getting a general answer). I guess I did a few small mistakes but all in all I hope I will get at least 5 out of 10 marks, since during the exam I answered exact the way how I typed right now, but I secretly knew I was doing something wrong but wasn't so sure exact what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the JavaDocs, you will note there are two `substring` methods

- [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)
- [substring(int beginIndex,
             int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

For your case, you probably only need the first one, for example...

```
s1.substring(s1.length() - 4);
```

Will return the last four characters of the `String`.  You would simply need to use the same technique on the second `String` and compare the results

I'm also not sure what the `for-loop` is trying to achieve...

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the spelling error of `s1lan` where the variable would have been `s1len`, I believe you did almost the right thing to rule out strings of shorter than 4 characters. Try `s1.length()` instead.

As far as the `for` loop is concerned, though, `(s1.substring() - 4.equals(s2.length() - 4))` is farther off the mark than you would have wanted.

You'll notice that `s1.substring()` doesn't specify the length, and returns a `String`, so `String - int` doesn't make sense. Within the `equals()` function, you have `int - int` so that's fine, but again you're probably not comparing what you intended to.

`(s1.substring(s1len - 4)).equals(s2.substring(s2len - 4))` would be closer to your intention, because that would give two substrings.

The `for` loop doesn't strike me as necessary in the first place. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986088/java-code-comparing-last-4-letters#comment36960833_23986088) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986088/java-code-comparing-last-4-letters#comment36960964_23986088) now that you're out of the exam, try compiling it and fix the errors as you find them. Writing a test helps too because you would be able to check that it is getting you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean compareLast4(String one, String two){

    if(one.length() != two.length() || one.length() < 4) return false;

    one = one.substring(one.length()-4);
    two = two.substring(two.length()-4);

    return one.equals(two);
}
```

Comment: If the length of either string is less than 4, the method should return false.

Comment: In the original problem, it never says the strings have to be the same size, so your "if(one.length() != two.length()) return false;" block is wrong. Also, you end up returning one.equals(two) no matter what, whereas it should return false if either are less than 4 (you don't actually check for this).

Comment: @Jug6ernaut , thank you for the specific answer, your code looks a bit longer but looks more easier to understand, although I have already chosen a final answer, I still appreciate your response.

Comment: @fgb, ahh thanks missed that.

Comment: @MattMettler sure, but if they arnt the same the same length then then the string will never be the same... & correct, before i assumed we were still comparing strings less than 4 chars long. Missed that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just in one line using regex :-)

```java
return  s1.length() >=4 && s2.length() >= 4 ? s1.matches(".*?" + s2.substring(s2.length()-4))
                                            : false;
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but I am learning Java using BlueJ at uni, still I appreciate your response.

Comment: The matches(regex) method is part of the standard java api... you can use it even with BlueJ.

Comment: What if `s1` is `"Hello"` and `s2` is `".*.*"` ?

Comment: OK, it has to be taken into account... i was only trying to make her think that there're alternative ways than simple for loops...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
public static boolean compareLastFourCharacters(String first, String second) {
    try {
        first = first.substring(first.length() - 4);
        return second.endsWith(first);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```